Dual boot not showing for windows 11/ ubuntu
I am not getting the options to choose from windows 11 or Ubuntu.
ubuntu boot priority
Ubuntu shows on the on the boot override but not on the priority list and it boots into windows every time
Windows is on 500gb drive
Ubuntu is on 250gb drive
boot settings
Data Format of Ubuntu drive: NTFS
Data Format of Windows drive: NTFS
Computer Specs
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5800x
Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX B550-F
Windows 11
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Boot repair solved the issue. I set boot priority to Ubuntu, and now it shows both Windows 11 and Ubuntu.
